# Haskell function signature error

Tags: haskell

I have the following function

```
encryptChar :: Char -> [Char] -> Char
encyptChar x z = z !! ((elemIndex) x cA)
```

Where cA is a list of Chars.

However, the function returns -Missing binding for variable "encryptChar" in type signature

Anybody has a suggestion? :)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you notice the typo? It's on the second line. First word.

Answer (score 5):

The first hit on Google for `missing binding for variable in type signature` gives [this page](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/sjt/craft2e/errors/hugsErrorsComplete.xml), which says, "The problem here is that the function has its type declared, but it is not actually defined in the module.". In your case, this is because you misspelled `encryptChar`.